# Restrict Glimpse for only admin users

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, glimpse

I want to do this via code if possible, I want to allow glimpse to be accessed only by administrative users, how can this be achieved?

The website states it is possible - cant seem to find the exact link though

http://getglimpse.com/

Answer (score 2):

You could turn glimpse off by default and restrict the `/glimpse.axd` config panel to administrators only:

```
<location path="glimpse.axd">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles="Admin"/>
        <deny users="*"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: How could I do this using code - I ideally want to say is user tom, jay or peter then allow them through...

Comment: I could be searching the database hence why I want to check by code

Comment: If you use roles you don't need to do it by code. Just grant all those users the custom role which you specify in your `web.config` as shown in my answer. I've used the `Admin` role in this example but you could create a special role called `Glimpse` for example and then simply grant those users this role.

Comment: The way @Darin suggested it would be my recommendation. But if you are looking for more than this, you would implement a `IGlimpseValidator` - here is an example https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Validator/UrlValidator.cs. Just note that with v1 this interface has changed slightly.

Comment: @anthonyv the link is broken?

Comment: Latest link is - https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/blob/master/source/Glimpse.Core/Policy/UriPolicy.cs and http://getglimpse.com/Help/Configuration shows more on how to use it. Hope that helps

Comment: Without using asp.net authorization, how to prevent users from hitting the glimpse.axd file?

Comment: Our corporation has it's relies on windows ntlm for user identification and a custom backend system for role management.  I understand I could build a provider to identify the roles from our custom backend system for use in the web.config however I do not want to inject another database hit for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

In Glimpse 1.4.1, they provide a GlimpseSecurityPolicy.cs that will easily allow you to set authorization in code instead of using the  element.